# Table Alias in Apache Cassandra / DataStax Enterprise

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Is it possible to have an alias for a table in Cassandra? DataStax Enterprise version we are using is 3.2.1

Your help will greatly be appreciated.

For ex:

```
 select s from example s where s.id='1234';
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no way to alias tables in Apache Cassandra.  You can alias returned column names using `as` ([reference](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-cassandra-2-0)), i.e.:

```sql
SELECT event_id, dateOf(created_at) as creation_date, blobAsText(content) as content FROM timeline;
```

Howver, you cannot alias tables.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alias a table in Cassandra.  And it is important to understand there is no reason to alias a table in Cassandra.  A table alias in a RDBMS query is helpful when a query involves more than one table such as a join.  That simply does not happen in Cassandra.